# specifying UIWebView Content size Or position

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

I'm using UIWebView to load .GIF images with the following code

```
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];        
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadData:self.selectedImageData MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

my problem is that my images vary in size ,
how can i make the images fit(stretch or shrink ) to the UIWebView size  ? OR 
how can i specify a fram in the UIWebView where i can load my data in  ?

i've tried
    [webView sizeToFit];
but it didn't work.

any suggestions on how to solve this problem

Comment: Is it possible to load html files instead and have them specify their image and its size in an IMG tag?

Comment: can i create those html files dynamically ? see i get my images from a web service

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this might help you

CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(60.0, 80.0);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [image drawInRect:imageRect];
        self.yourImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: and how would i be able to load this image in a UIWebView ... my question is about .gif images in UIWebView